# Undefined control sequence for citestyle acmnumeric when uploading to arXiv

Tags: arxiv, acmart

I'm using the `acmart` class with the following options:

```latex
sigconf,
nonacm=true,
natbib=false
```

For uploading the document to arXiv, I prepare and bundle all files using [`arxiv-collector`](https://github.com/djsutherland/arxiv-collector), which usually does the heavy lifting when dealing with arXiv's old TeX Live version. However, now I'm getting the following error log:

```
[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3283311/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2016/11/16 v1.24 Typesetting articles for Association of
Computing Machinery
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/totpages/totpages.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.268 \citestyle
{acmnumeric}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.268 \citestyle
{acmnumeric}
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
```

As the log shows, `\citestyle{acmnumeric}` appears to be an undefined control sequence to arXiv / TeX Live 2016. Locally, I'm using Tex Live 2020 and everything is fine.

Are their additional files that aren't picked up by `arxiv-collector`, which I should bundle as well? Or how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log shows, arXiv is using acmart 2016/11/16 v1.24, whereas locally I used 2020/04/30 v1.71. From this newer class version I was using various features not available in v1.24, which made the arXiv compilation fail.

I was able to resolve this issue by putting the `acmart.cls` file into the root directory and uploading it as well.

Comment: indeed the texlive arXiv uses is from 2016 and the newer acmart.cls file is recommended if you're making use of any of its newer functionality.